# Which Role for start stop VM instance only

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I create a role for a user who only be able to start / stop a certain VM instance?

I need the developer user, who uses the VM, to start stop the VM instance, so idle times are not being paid for the VM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide only the permission for starting and stoping the VM, you can set a custom role with the [corresponding permission start and stop](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/#rest-resource-v1instances)

Or, and it's not a good practice at least privilege perspective, you can assign a pre-defined role `roles/compute.instanceAdmin` for this. Not a good practice because here, the user can create and delete VM in addition of stop and start

**UPDATE**

You can ask your developer to install `gcloud` sdk and run this command

`gcloud compute instances start <your instance name> --zone <your zone> --project <your project id>`

(replace `start`by `stop` for stopping).

If you prefer that they go to the console, add the permission `compute.intances.list` for allowing them to view all the VM and then they could start and stop *them* on the GUI -> Yes, you can limit to only 1 VM, they will see all and they could start and stop all through the GUI

Finally, you can write a very easy program for starting and stopping the VM by calling the computes API.

It's your choice!!

Comment: Thx for reply Guillaume. Is this a code I need to establish somewhere ? It wasn't clear to me in the docu, how this is to get going. The user has a gmail account if thats something of use for login to start/stop the VM.

Comment: Hey Guillaume, thx for reply and update. I ran the command and received a permission error. I checked gcloud help command, but didn't see how to authenticate a developer user. Probably I also need to add the dev-user with respective start / stop permission for a specific instance. Not sure yet about how to do it.

Comment: insufficient authentication scopes

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't see how to authenticate a developer user"? You don't know how to perform the action being identified as a developer?

Comment: wanted to know how the authorization workflow is with the user-permissions on GCloud and user-credentials in the engine start-stop command. Goal is, to create users with start-stop engine permission only, over ssh. The whole working workflow ... where does the ssh login how ?

Comment: The users also have to connect over SSH to the VM?

Comment: yes, over putty with ssh authorizing .pkk and tunneling